# After adding <crontab> in my config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, crontab

After adding `<crontab></crontab>` in mymodule's **config.xml** file I got error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mymodule_Helper_Data' not found in
>   **/app/Mage.php on line 547

in my config.xml

```
<helpers>
    <mymodule>
     <class>Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper</class>
    </mymodule>
</helpers>
```

and cron tag

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
      <mycron>
        <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
        <run><model>mymodule/observer::cancelOrders</model></run>
            </mycron>
    </crontab>
```

Please suggest in which direction i have to check the error.
Thank you for help in adv..

Comment: make sure you have created Data.php file in module's helper Directory

Comment: @Piyush Data.php is available in Helper directory.

Comment: Please share  full config.xml code?

Comment: also folder  share the path location of `Data.php' of Mypackage_Mymodule

Comment: Please create Helper directory and inside directory create Data.php

Comment: /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento19/app/code/local/Mypackage/Mymodule           and in that /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento19/app/code/local/Mypackage/Mymodule/Helper/Data.php

Answer (score 0):

Remove following code from **config.xml** if you are not using any helper class method.

```
<helpers>
    <mymodule>
     <class>Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper</class>
    </mymodule>
</helpers>
```

or create **Helper** directory and inside that directory create **Data.php**

```
<?php
class Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

Comment: Data.php is inside Helper directory.

Comment: in my Data.php  class name should be Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper or Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper_Data?

Comment: Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper_Data

Answer (score 0):

**app/etc/modules/Mypackage_Mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Mypackage_Mymodule>
          <active>true</active>
          <codePool>local</codePool>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mypackage_Mymodule>
      </modules>
    </config>
```

**app/code/local/Mypackage/Mymodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mypackage_Mymodule>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mypackage_Mymodule>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <mymodule>
        <class>Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper</class>
      </mymodule>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <mymodule>
        <class>Mypackage_Mymodule_Model</class>
      </mymodule>
    </models>
  </global>    
    <crontab>
        <jobs>            
            <mymodule_cancelorders>
                <schedule><cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>mymodule/cron::cancelOrders</model></run>
            </mymodule_cancelorders>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Mypackage/Mymodule/Helper/Data.php**

```
class Mypackage_Mymodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**app/code/local/Mypackage/Mymodule/Model/Cron.php**

```
class Mypackage_Mymodule_Model_Cron{    

        public function cancelOrders(){
            //do something
        } 
}
```

Comment: I have created Observer.php inside Model.

Comment: Why? Are you using any event?

Comment: I want to cancel pending orders using cron as per schedule.

Comment: So that you can use cron.php as well as please use one free module cron doctor to check which cron process is running or which cron process is dead or pending from magento admin section.

link of cron doctor - 

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cron-doctor.html

Answer (score 0):

Here we can mention the **config.xml**  file mention the following code

```
<config>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <my_cron>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>mymodule/observer::functionName</model>
            </run>
        </my_cron>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Then call that function in **observer.php** file

```
class Firstname_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
  public function functionName()
  {
     // Do the operations here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below cronjob code will execute at 12:30PM every day.

```
<job name="test_customer_export" instance="Vendorname\modulename\Cron\Customer" method="execute">
    <schedule>30 12 * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

30 is minute
12 is hours

Comment: If you want to run cronjob at 12:30 am every night than schedule format should be: <schedule>0 0 * * *</schedule>

Comment: for reference please refer examples from this link: https://crontab.guru/examples.html

Comment: Question was for Magento 1.